# Correct Concept for Object-Oriented Programming

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, polymorphism

I am asking this question to see if my understanding of how Object-Orientation works is correct. Let's say that I have an abstract super class that has several methods all with some sort of implementation.

```
@interface SuperClass : UIViewController
- (void)methodOne;

// Other public stuff


@end
```

.......

```
@implementation SuperClass

- (void)methodOne
{
    //some implementation
}

- (someObject *)objectMethod
{
     //more implementation
}

@end
```

Then If I am implementing a subclass of that:

```
@interface SubClass : SuperClass

@end
```

.......

```
@implementation SubClass

- (void)methodOne
{
    // override method implementation code
}

@end
```

So from the example above, if I create a view controller, which is a class of SubClass, will it essentially create a SubClass object and automatically add the implementation of all the SuperClass methods? The idea that I am getting at is if when the preprocessor runs, does it take any method that has not been overridden in the subclass and just place the super class code method into that class for it's use? In this case I only overrode the 'methodOne' method from the super class and left the 'objectMethod' method alone. Does that mean my SubClass will utilize the new overridden 'methodOne' implementation and use the SuperClasses' 'objectMethod' implementation?

Thanks a bunch! Let me know if I need to clarify something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you redefine `methodOne` in the SubClass implementation, instances of SubClass will use the redefined implementation.  If there is no redefinition the SubClass implementation, it will look to the implementation of SuperClass for a definition.  This process recursively continues through higher super classes until it finds a definition.

If you'd like to slightly modify the definition in the SubClass, you could do something like:

```
-(void) methodOne{
    // Some code to add before SuperClass's implementation is called
    ....

    // Call SuperClass's implementation
    [super methodOne];

    // Some code to add after SuperClass's implementation is called
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really clearing things up for me. I also posted a comment below to a related question. If you had any additional insight on that I would greatly appreciate it as well! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The subclass gets all the superclasses methods. If you override one then that method no longer has the superclasses implementation of it.  So in this case, you will get the objectMethod of the superclass and the methodOne of the subclass when you instantiate a subclass instance and call either method.

Comment: Awesome! I am happy to see that my understanding is correct. One other thing that I am having a difficult time with is using variables from my superclass in my subclass. In my specific example I am creating a game and the SuperClass is the game and is where the game gets instantiated as a property. My SubClass needs to override methods that use the same property object, but obviously I don't have access to it. I also can't make this property public. How can I provide an override that requires access to another classes property? I can't use delegation for it either.

Comment: I think there are two solutions to this problem: 1) Make the property public.  But since you said you can't do that... 2) Make some sort of method in the superclass that the subclass can call using self that will get the relevent data you need out of the private properties... so let's say you have int x and int y and you don't want to expose those, but you need x+y, write a public method -(NSInteger)xplusy that does the calculation and returns it, and that should be available to use in the subclass... or you know -(NSInteger)x if you just wanted x.